# Get system's date ddmmyyyy

Tags: java, android, date

It's probably an easy question but how do you get the system date in format as `ddmmyyyy` in eclipse. So without any letters, spaces or other characters?

Comment: Is this in an Eclipse plugin or an Android app?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
String todayAsString = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());
```

Eclipse is an IDE. Java is the language. Googling for "format a date in Java" and "current date in Java" would have led you to hundreds of pages telling you the answer. What matters is the language: Java. Not the IDE, which is just a tool to generate and compile Java code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code, And can change the format to whatever you like.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "MMddyyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        // formatting
        System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Merlin: you're appending an empty String to the toString() representation of the SimpleDateFormat object. You just want `String dateString = format.format(new Date());` `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)` returns the formatted date.

Comment: Which variable contains the date?

Comment: One more question, how can I add one day to the date?

Comment: @Merlin: google is your friend. Google for "add one day to a date in Java", and I'm sure you'll get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
               Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
               String cal_for_month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               String cal_for_year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                String cal_for_day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```